# How Laravel manages sessions?

Tags: php, database, session, laravel, laravel-4

I need some help regarding on how Laravel manages sessions. When I was programming with pure PHP, i was using the global variable $_SESSION. This way, when I wanted to retrieve information regarding an user, I was finding the user in the database by $_SESSION['id'] variable. I do not understand how Laravel works with this. Can you guide to some guides, please? Thanks in advance.

Comment: RTFM! http://laravel.com/docs/session

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As pointed in the first comment, Laravel has it's own Session controlling system, that can be accessed, at any point of your application, by using the `Session` facade.

To store a value in the session, you do

```
Session::put('key', 'value');
```

To retrieve the value:

```
$value = Session::get('key');
```

Answer (score 1):

Besides reading documentation, you have to know that Laravel has dedicated **Session** class. By using that class at different points in Laravel request you can track users activity (among others thing that can be done). There is very interesting session/code flow from initial request to response so take a look - that is the best way to learn.